# Import paragraph from another file in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I have a problem. I want to use an object from another component in the `ability.component.html` file. It seems that last paragraph (`h1`) doesn't work. Why is that?

---

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: `./app.component.html`,
    styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {     
    constructor(){ }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<p>app.component work</p>
<app-baza></app-baza>
```

**model.ts**

```
export interface Human {
    name: string,
    wzrost: number,
    age: number,
    pozycja: PozycjaNaBoisku,
}

export enum PozycjaNaBoisku {
    rozgrywajacy,
    skrzydlowy,
    center,
}
```

**baza.component.ts**

```
import { Human, PozycjaNaBoisku } from '../model'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-baza',
    templateUrl: './baza.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./baza.component.css']
})
export class BazaComponent implements OnInit {
    humans: Human[] = [
      {
          name: "Jordan",
          wzrost: 199,
          age: 23,
          pozycja: PozycjaNaBoisku.skrzydlowy,
      },
      {
          name: "Shaq",
          wzrost: 218,
          age: 34,
          pozycja: PozycjaNaBoisku.center,
      }]

      human: Human = this.humans[0];

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**baza.component.html**

```
<p>{{human.name}}</p>   
<app-ability></app-ability>
```

**ability.component.ts**

```
import { Human, PozycjaNaBoisku } from '../model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-ability',
    templateUrl: './ability.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ability.component.css']
})
export class AbilityComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() human: Human;

    nameColor: string = "blue";

    PozycjaNaBoisku = PozycjaNaBoisku;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}  
}
```

**ability.component.html**

```
<h1>{{humans[1].name}}</h1>
<p>ability works</p>
```

and here `h1` doesn't work. Why?

Comment: What does "h1 does not work" means? It doesn't show anything?

Comment: doesn't show antything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't send anything as input. Ahhh, you really need to read any example of Angular component interaction (just search for "Angular Input" and you will get results like [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction)).

For your specific case you need to do the following:

**baza.component.html**

```
<p>{{human.name}}</p>   
<app-ability [humans]="humans"></app-ability>
```

**ability.component.ts**

```
import { Human, PozycjaNaBoisku } from '../model';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-ability',
    templateUrl: './ability.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./ability.component.css']
})
export class AbilityComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() humans: Human[];

    nameColor: string = "blue";

    PozycjaNaBoisku = PozycjaNaBoisku;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {}  
}
```

That should be it. Remember, always do your research, this is quite a common thing in Angular and the answer can be found anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

DawidR ,i think your idea is parse data from baza component to ability component
there are several ways to do that go to follow link to get better understanding,

https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb